TimeoutException in Selenium, Python
The objective of my program is to record the text from some HTML elements in 25 specific webpages. In fact, there are 4 columns of text rows and clicking on each of them the div with two needed span elements appereas. Those two elements do not exist in the DOM before the mouse click. The first one (English variable) is recorded successfully.
Here are the methods I was trying to use for text extraction:
text = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[' + str(column) + ']/p[' + str(word) + ']/a')))
actions.click(text).perform()
English = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
   EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/h3/span[1]'))
)
Ukrainian = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/span'))
)
print(English.text + " " + Ukrainian.text)

The unique specific of that element is the presence of some throbber that exists before the element emergence. But the throbber is not displayable when some user uses the website. It is visible only in case of Selenium webdriver use. Here's a screenshot:
The throbber that is displayable before the visibility of /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/span
The error I get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\DW\GlossaryProjects\Functional\Selenium\start.py", line 130, in <module>
Ukrainian = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

What I need is to obtain all needed text values from /html/body/div[2]/h3/span[1] and from /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/span to be able to see it in terminal and put it into the database as a result.

Can't help much without the URL of the website or at least the HTML of the page. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
